# Constrained lenses

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

Suppose I have

```
getXY :: X a -> Y a
setXY :: C a => X a -> Y a -> X a
```

Is it possible to write something lens-like that imposes `C a` only when setting? I'm interested in both Van Laarhoven and profunctor-style optics.

Answer (score 2):

I can't say for certain, but with exactly the types you've given, I don't see how.

That said, are you being overly restrictive in your types?  Could it be possible that `setXY` might be allowed to have the type:

```hs
setXY :: C b => X a -> Y b -> X b
```

In other words, the constraint `C` matters for the second argument and the output but not for the input?  If so, then you *can* make the following lens:

```hs
lensXY :: C b => Lens (X a) (X b) (Y a) (Y b)
lensXT = lens getXY setXY
```

This is still a somewhat strange lens.  For instance, say you have a value of type `x :: X Int`, but `Int` is not an instance of `C`.  Then, you'll get an error if you try `x ^. lensXY`.  Funny enough, this isn't a flaw with the lens so much as with `^.`, which has an overly restrictive type.

Now consider if we redefine `^.` as follows:

```hs
(^.) :: s -> Lens s t a b -> a
s ^. l = getConst (l Const s)
```

Note that the function definition is exactly the same as [the previous definition](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-5.2/docs/src/Control.Lens.Getter.html#%5E.), but we've changed the type signature (it's more general for lenses but more constrained for everything else).  Now, we can *almost* execute `x ^. lensXY`, but the problem now is that GHC doesn't know what types to use for `t` and `b`.  Specifically, it needs a type that satisfies the constraint `C`.  So, let's make one final assumption: that there is an instance `C Bool`.  Then, we can write `x ^. lensXY @Bool`, and it type-checks and extracts the `Y a` value even though `a` is not an instance of `C`.

On the other hand, using `%~` or similar still demands the class constraint.

Comment: Yeah, I think I'm just not going to be able to have such a lens. In the actual application, I think that's okay; it's just kind of annoying. I'm much more annoyed that GHC still doesn't allow patterns to have different signatures for matching vs. constructing.

Comment: Pattern synonyms do allow [different constraints](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/users_guide/exts/pattern_synonyms.html#typing-of-pattern-synonyms) for what they "prove" vs what they "require" -- could that be helpful?

Comment: No, that's not enough. There should be *three* constraints. See [this proposal](https://github.com/ghc-proposals/ghc-proposals/blob/master/proposals/0042-bidir-constr-sigs.rst) I drafted long ago that was accepted but that's never been implemented.

Comment: Specifically: required to match, provided by matching, and required to construct don't relate to each other in any consistent way, but the current system pretends they do.